# Use UID to emit on flask-socketio

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I'm trying to make a Skype Web using flask and flask_socketio, I already know that I must use the `room` parameter in sending to send a private message, but the examples I've seen so far use the SID, which changes if the user restarts the page. So I made every user who logs in have their own ID, but I don't know how to make it work on `emit ('an_event', room = id)`. How do I get the room sent to my custom ID instead of a session ID?

**Edit:** another way, is there any way to make the SID not change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flask-SocketIO server does not know of your application-specific user IDs. What you need to do is create a mapping between the SIDs assigned to each client connection and the user IDs that are represented by each of those clients. You can do this by adding connect and disconnect handlers. Example:

```py
user_to_sid = {}
sid_to_user = {}

@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect(environ):
    user_id = authenticate_user(environ)
    user_to_sid[user_id] = request.sid
    sid_to_user[request.sid] = user_id

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def on_disconnect():
    user_id = sid_to_user[request.sid]
    del user_to_sid[user_id]
    del sid_to_user[request.sid]
```

Once you have the mapping, you can easily find the current SID for a given user or viceversa.

Comment: But after refresh the page, the SID changes. If i use the old SID, is it still working?

Comment: Ow, i think i understood your reasoning

Comment: If you refresh the page then the disconnect handler would remove the old sid, and then after that a new connect handler will be invoked with the new sid. So the dictionaries would automatically get updated.